# Fix an Image in collapsingToolbar regardless of scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface

[image: THis is my layout]

I have searched a lot but haven't found a solution for this.
What i really want is to have a collapsing toolbar layout which collapses but an imageview inside it should not move   . it should remain fixed and the nestedscrollview should scroll above it . Its just like as seen in spotify profile page . It is somewhat similar to position:fixed which we use in css
Thanks :)

Here is my code

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileBg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>



                </FrameLayout>



                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>



            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fb123"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>
```

what i want is the small square image at the top should remain fixed and the big image below the text "Box" should slide above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it could be easily achieved by just setting the background image of a RelativeLayout

Here is my xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileBg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/fb123"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="fill"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- content for the scrollview goes here. -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sjfsjfjsjfs
                fsdfsfjsdflsjdfslfjsdlfjfsdfldslfjdslfjdsjfsdljfsf
                sdflsdjfldsjfslfjsdfldsfjslfjsdlfdsf
                sdfjdsfljdslfjdsljfldsjfdsjflsjdflsdjfdsf
                sdfsdlfjsdlfjsd
                fsdjlfjsdlfjdslfjsdlfjdslfdsf
                djfsdlfjslfsjfsfsfsdlfj
                sdflfjsdlfjsdfl"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`